# How to distinguish between an item move and a deletion

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, item

I have a question about SharePoint `2010` and the technical differentiation between an item move and a deletion in an `event receiver`.
As I could see, when moving a document to another library, the `ItemDeleting` and `ItemDeleted` events are also called. 
So how do I differentiate in the event receiver whether a document is really deleted or just moved to another library?

Has anyone here already gained experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer. 
In the `SPItemEventProperties` in the `event receiver` is the property `AfterUrl`.
On deletion this property is `null`, on movement it contains the new url of the item.